# Date Range Picker in 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using the [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) plugin for bootstrap and I am trying to get the values in 24hour format. I have set the option `timePicker24Hour: true` but it still doesn't return it in 24 hour format.

This is my code:

```
$("#reportdatetime").daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm'
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/k67xfa1g/1/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the correct locale format.To display time in 24 hours format use the following -

```
$("#reportdatetime").daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm'
    }
});
```

working example : https://jsfiddle.net/Ly0jh5pz/2

Comment: `H:MM` is incorrect. It should be `H:mm`. `MM` is used for months.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Arvind

Comment: you can use both H:mm and H:MM.

Comment: Incorrect. Check your fiddle. `H:MM` is giving incorrect result by default in your minute field. Even though the minute input box shows 00, the value being set in the date field is that of the month.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
    $('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
        "timePicker": true,
        "timePicker24Hour": true,
        "startDate": "03/27/2016",
        "endDate": "04/02/2016"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set AM/PM format into it if you want: [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) is some examples.
And[here](http://momentjs.com/) is describing how to use moment formats.